# Minimize: which algorithm is in use?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How can I know which algorithm has been used by `Minimize` to solve a given problem?

Can I force `Minimize` to use a specific algorithm ?

Comment: What particular algorithm did you have in mind?

Comment: Is it solving with CAD or with Lagrangian ? I know that if all my constraints are eq constraint it will use Lagrangian. However is there a way to verify ? Also If I include the `Timing` results in a paper I should include which algorithm has been used to solve as well. I don't think just believing the docs is enough.

Comment: Some details are given [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#4313). The exact details of how and when it switches would seem to be a trade secret.

Comment: I have no problem with the trade secret but it should at least tell the user, what methods has been used otherwise what should one write in paper ? Solved by Mathematica in X seconds with trade secret algorithm ?

Comment: have you seen this? https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationExact.html.  Also you can specify `Method->"CAD"` for example.  (unfortunately I don't see a listing of specifiable methods)

Comment: Yes I have seen that but how can I make sure that it really solves using that method, that the promise of the docs.  On `Method->"CAD"` where can I specify that ? any example ? There is no hint in Minimize docs. I get `Minimize::optx: Unknown option Method`

Comment: just like this: `Minimize[x^2, {x}, Method -> "CAD"]`  (version 10.1)

Comment: Hm mine is 9 :( So v10.1 have that option ?

Comment: i guess.. I note the `Method` option isn't documented in v10 either, i just found that by mistake.

Comment: `Minimize[x^2, {x}, Method -> "CAD"]` doesn't work for me in windows version 9. I get an ***Unknown option ...*** message.